# Do we get INSTALL_REFERRER broadcast when app was already installed and open from Play Store?

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play, android-broadcast

Lets say I have a link with the referrer id and it is opened in Play Store. The app can either be installed or not installed. I understand that this broadcast is received the app when the app is installed.

But What happens when the app was already installed on such a device and the user clicks on open button on Play Store to launch the application? I want to show a custom screen in this scenario.

Comment: why don't you check if app is installed on the device or not ? If its installed you can process the click of link in your own way & if its not then it will redirect to playstore

Comment: the end user would just receive a link which is opened in the Google Play Store. How can i check whether the app was installed or not during this workflow where the app is not installed.